# Setting query result as default column value without using triggers

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create table with default primary key (not autoincrement), similar with oracle

```
fk_id varchar2(32) default sys_guid()
```

so table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE `t_table` (
    `fk_id` TEXT DEFAULT 'select lower(hex(randomblob(16)))' UNIQUE,
    `fv_name`   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`fk_id`)
);
```

and yes, i'm getting this select as string value while inserting.

so is there any solution without using triggers?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `'select lower(hex(randomblob(16)))'` is enclosing the subquery as a string/text literal and will work only once as UNIQUE has been specified (no need as making the column PRIMARY KEY implies UNIQUE) thus any subsequent inserts would fail.

Assuming that you want the DEFAULT value to be the result of the of *lower(hex(randomblob(16))* then you cannot use a subquery as the value is then not considered as a CONSTANT.

- > For the purposes of the DEFAULT clause, an expression is considered
  >   constant if it contains no sub-queries, column or table references,
  >   bound parameters, or string literals enclosed in double-quotes instead
  >   of single-quotes.[SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Instead you could remove the select and just use the expression, which is then considered CONSTANT.

However, to do so, you need to adhere to

> If the default value of a column is an expression in **parentheses**, then
>   the expression is evaluated once for each row inserted and the results
>   used in the new row. [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Thus you could use :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_table` (
    `fk_id` TEXT DEFAULT (lower(hex(randomblob(16)))) UNIQUE,
    `fv_name`   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`fk_id`)
);
```

Of course should the value not be unique, which would be increasingly likely, then this would result in the row not being inserted.

Comment: thanks, my example with single quotes was formatted that way because of default data modeller, which inserted it that way.